# Не корректное изменение QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не могу разобраться почему не изменяется `QListWidget` хотя в консоль он выводит, что в `listwidget` данная строка изменена. Как исправить

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MainWindwos(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.asd = Click()
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))
        self.setFixedSize(400, 600)
        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.resize(400, 600)
        self.listwidget.addItem('привет')
        self.listwidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.listwidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.asd.edit_item)

class Click:
    def edit_item(self, item):
        self.main = MainWindwos()
        g = self.main.listwidget.itemAt(item)
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.dialog.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dialog)
        self.edit.resize(200, 30)
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.dialog)
        self.push.setText('сохранить')
        self.push.move(0, 50)
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: g.setText(self.edit.text()))
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: print(g.text()))
        self.dialog.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindwos()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Кст, а почему вы не используете layout'ты? С ними не нужно думать о размерах виджетах и их расположении, плюсом они могу автоматически менять положение и размер виджетов. Есть QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QFormLayout, Еще, диалоги рекомендуется через exec показывать, а не show -- тогда диалог станет модальным. У вас диалог очень простой, поэтому можно вместо своего использовать стандартный: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText

Comment: @gil9red Сам без понятия почему не пользуюсь ими. Просто не понимаю как они конкретно работают (

Comment: Смотрите, у виджетов есть метод `setLayout`, нужно создать layout (если виджеты нужно вертикально разместить, тогда `QVBoxLayout`), и через `layout.addWidget` добавить виджеты (`layout.addWidget(button))`, после вызвать у виджета `setLayout(layout)`. Все. После этого виджеты будут как влитые. Для QMainWindow и QScrollArea есть исключения -- они оперируют внутри себя виджетом, поэтому для них сначала создается виджет, у него вызывается setLayout, а после тот виджет устанавливается на них. Для QMainWindow это метод setCentralWidget

Comment: Вот тут есть мой пример работы с компоновщиками (layout): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/bin2str/gui.py#L54 . Уровнем выше есть скриншот

Comment: @gil9red Благодарю буду разбираться )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в строке `self.main = MainWindwos()`. Используя ее, вы каждый раз создаете новое окно с его списком, хотя изменить хотите значение в старом окне.

В `Click` нужно передавать ссылку на окно, с которым он будет работать:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindwos(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.asd = Click(self)

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))
        self.setFixedSize(400, 600)

        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.resize(400, 600)
        self.listwidget.addItem('привет')
        self.listwidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.listwidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.asd.edit_item)


class Click:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main

    def edit_item(self, item):
        item = self.main.listwidget.itemAt(item)

        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.dialog.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))

        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dialog)
        self.edit.setText(item.text())
        self.edit.resize(200, 30)

        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.dialog)
        self.push.setText('сохранить')
        self.push.move(0, 50)
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: item.setText(self.edit.text()))
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: print(item.text()))

        self.dialog.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = MainWindwos()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```